# Firefox hangs during heavy for loop

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

When my extension starts a heavy job (a `for` loop which will trigger more processes down the road), Firefox stops responding. It won't resume to work until my extension completes the job.

My extension takes around 16000 milliseconds to complete its work. Is there a way to execute my script asynchronously? Or Is there any other way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you considered [using web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers) ?

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR:** Yes, there is a way. Make your code run in short iterations and yield using `setTimeout`.

<strike>There's no such thing as threads in JavaScript</strike>. Okay, yes, there is the [Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Worker) API. But I still think threads are unnecessary and evil (race conditions, deadlocks, etc. – it has all been covered before). Browser Extensions may be the only use case where threads in JavaScript could have any merit. But it's still best avoided.

So. If not threads, what then? JavaScript has an **event loop**, which is a curse and a blessing. Every time a piece of your code runs, all other things on the page are halted (that's why the page becomes unresponsive). To prevent this from happening, you should make each piece of your code run as fast as possible and then **yield** to other events in the event queue.

To do this, replace your `for` loop with a recursive function that calls itself via `setTimeout`. So instead of this:

```
var length = collection.length; // <-- 2 gazillion
var i;
for (i=0; i<length; i+=1) {
    lengthyOperation(i);
}
// Script yields here.
```

... you'll do something like this:

```
var length = collection.length; // <-- still 2 gazillion
var i;
function lengthyOperationAsync() {
    lengthyOperation(i); // <-- still lengthy
    i += 1;
    if (i < length) {
        setTimeout(lengthyOperationAsync, 0);
    }
    // Script yields here.
}
```

This way, the browser can update the page and handle user input in between iterations of your lengthy `for` loop. There is only one drawback: it may take longer than usual in some browsers. This is because [timer resolution](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2011/12/14/timer-resolution-in-browsers/); some browsers have a minimum delay of **4ms** when using `setTimeout`, even if you specify `0`.

By the way, there is a proposal for a function called [setImmediate](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2011/09/19/script-yielding-with-setimmediate/), which is meant for this exact purpose – but most browsers haven't implemented it yet.

Comment: Could whoever down-voted this please [explain why](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#behonest)?

Comment: It wasn't me, but my guess would be because you implied web workers don't exist, which is pretty much exactly what was asked for, regardless of suitability to solve his problem.

Comment: @chris: thanks for pointing that out. You're probably right. I've amended the answer to avoid confusion.